# Failing to execute google cloud Speech API

Tags: c#, google-cloud-endpoints, speech-to-text

I have registered on Google cloud platform went through the  authentication steps and created the required JSON as suggested [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api).
On downloading the Google cloud SDk(requirement for setting up environment variable) and trying to install the installation fails my Os is win 7 64-bit.
On trying to set environment directly(My computer>advance settings> environment variable) and running the code mentioned in given link I get the error as please check value of environment variable Google_Application_credential
[error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSdME.png)

error Message:-

> system.InvalidOperationException: Error reading credential file from
>   location. please check the value of the environment variable
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.defaultcredentialprovider

Please help!

Comment: It is better to insert error text, not an image.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks.. have added the error message as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use those commands with the right path to make it work :

SET GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=FILE_PATH/credentials.json (name of the file)

SET GCLOUD_PROJECT=PROJECT_NAME

Comment: had set Google_application_credentials in the above way but didn't work, as for cloud_project couldn't install the cloud_sdk even that is giving error.

Comment: Did you correctly download the .json and placed it on your directory location?

Comment: Yes as given in  the steps.. I authenticated in same way and downloaded the JSON. Am I facing  the issue as I was unable to install gcloud sdk and set environment variable using gcloud sdk